# Python 2.7.x - unicode issue

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I'm scraping this site `www.soundkartell.de`, and I'm facing some unicode issues:

```
results =[] 
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.select('a[href*="alternative"]'):
        artist = article.h2.text                    
        results.append(artist.encode('latin1').decode("utf-8"))

 print artist # Din vän Skuggan 
 print results # [u'Din v\xe4n Skuggan']
```

I have `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`at the top of my file.

1. why does python print scraped data correctly and not the appended data?
2. how do I fix the unicode issue?

I am using `Python 2.7.x`

Comment: As an aside, `de` is the country code for Deutschland (ie. Germany).  Denmark is `dk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely do not actually have a problem.  What you are seeing is a side effect of how python prints things:

**Sample Code:**

```
artist = 'Din vän Skuggan'
artists = [artist]
print 'artist:', artist
print 'artists:', artists
print 'str:', str(artist)
print 'repr:', repr(artist)
```

**Produces:**

```
artist: Din vän Skuggan
artists: ['Din v\xc3\xa4n Skuggan']
str: Din vän Skuggan
repr: 'Din v\xc3\xa4n Skuggan'
```

So as can be seen above, when python prints a list, it use the `repr()` for the items in the list.  In both cases you have the same contents, python is just showing it differently.

**Side Note:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

At top of your script, is useful for string literals with unicode text in your code.